# How can I send "special" data in a POST request using PHP

Tags: python, php, curl

So I found a `Python` code that is doing what I want to do, but I can't find a way to get it working in PHP (I have tried many times to translate them).

Here is the Python code :

```
def restpost(url, payload, head=None):

   if head is not None:
      r = s.post(url, data=payload, timeout=90, stream=False, headers=head, verify=pem)
   else:
      r = s.post(url, data=payload, timeout=90, stream=False, verify=pem)
   commit_data = r.json()
   return commit_data 


restpost(URL, json.dumps(switch))
```

So, I know the URL, and here, `json.dumps(switch))` is `{"intrusion_settings": {"active_mode": "away"}}`

How can I do this in PHP? I tried many many ways, but nothing worked. Even when the request was sent successfully, it wasn't working.

If you want to go deeper in what I am trying to do, here is the python code that I want to do in PHP: `https://github.com/dynasticorpheus/gigasetelements-cli` (only the switch_modus part)

Thank you if you can help!

Comment: `nothing worked`, `it wasn't working` - what does this mean?  What did you try?  What does `special data` mean? You'll get a better response here if you show that you've made some effort to solve your problem yourself.  We're here because we want to help, but SO isn't a code-writing service. Show us what you've tried and what happened.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `json_encode` function.

---

**Example**

```
<?php
$arr = [
        "intrusion_settings" => [
            "active_mode" => "away"
    ]
];

echo json_encode($arr); // {"intrusion_settings":{"active_mode":"away"}}
```

---

**Possible solution**

```
$url='URL';
$payload = [
        "intrusion_settings" => [
            "active_mode" => "away"
    ]
];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type:application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // add this line if you have problem with SSL
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // add this line if you have problem with SSL

/**
You might need those lines for your .pem certification files
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__.'/yourcertfilename.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, __DIR__.'/yourcertfilename.pem');
*/
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

---

**Manual**

[Executable code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba9a1715439050fe19777d53036ae9666e096f74)

[PHP: json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

[PHP: cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: @JSE-Faucet It would be great if you accept and vote up my answer then :)